# Scrapy: CloseSpider in start_requests doesn't work

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to use CloseSpide in `def start_requests(self)`, however, it seems that my command is ignored.

Here my console output. After `scrapy.exceptions.CloseSpider` my spider seems to continue crawling.

```
WARNING:root:Scraper in DEBUG mode
i =======  1
i =======  2
i =======  3
i =======  4
i =======  5
i =======  6
i =======  7
i =======  8
i =======  9
i =======  10
WARNING:root:############ Reached 10. ############
2020-01-03 09:52:37 [root] WARNING: ############ Reached 10. ############
Error while obtaining start requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Marc/.local/share/virtualenvs/scrapy-Qon0LmmU/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 127, in _next_request
    request = next(slot.start_requests)
  File "/Users/Marc/Desktop/Dev/Scraper/scrapy/spider/spider/spiders/spider.py", line 66, in start_requests
    raise CloseSpider("############ Reached 10. ############")
scrapy.exceptions.CloseSpider
Dropped: Missing website for: Dimensions Festival 2012
{'pk': 7, 'name': 'Dimensions Festival 2012', 'website': ''}
Dropped: Missing website for: Hideout 2012
{'pk': 5, 'name': 'Hideout 2012', 'website': ''}
Dropped: Missing website for: Beacons Festival 2012
{'pk': 6, 'name': 'Beacons Festival 2012', 'website': ''}
```

**spider.py**

```
def start_requests(self):
    for i in range(1, 100):
        print("i ======= ", i)
        if i == 10:
            logging.warning("############ Reached 10. ############")
            raise CloseSpider("############ Reached 10. ############")
        yield scrapy.Request("https://www.somewebsite.com/api-internal/v1/events/%s/?format=json" % i)
```

Comment: I believe that `start_requests` isn't technically a *callback* (where the exception should be raised) - just something that should be an iterable of initial requests... so if you replace your `raise ...` with a simple `return` to signal there's no more requests to be processed - that might well work (I've not tested that's the case...)

Comment: Hi Jon, didn't solve it, unfortunately.

Comment: Did request 11 complete? Requests sent before 10 will still be completed, even after CloseSpider has been raised.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately `start_requests` has unique functionality and is not treated like a callback. The easiest hack for this is to ignore it with a temp url:

```py
def start_requests(self):
    # start crawl with local file
    yield Request('file:///tmp/file.html')

def parse(self, response):
    # add your start requests logic here
    raise CloseSpider('works here!')
```

Alternatively depending on your use case you can look into cleaner solutions like Scrapy Signals[1]

1 - https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html